# How to sort a tuple based on a value within the list of tuples

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

In python, I wish to sort tuples based on the value of their last element. For example, i have a tuple like the one below.

```
tuples = [(2,3),(5,7),(4,3,1),(6,3,5),(6,2),(8,9)]
```

which after sort I wish to be in this format.

```
tuples = [(4,3,1),(6,2),(2,3),(6,3,5),(5,7),(8,9)]
```

How do i get to doing that?

Comment: Please show what you have tried yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Povide [`list.sort`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/sort.html#sort) with an appropriate key function that returns the last element of a tuple:

```
tuples.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
from operator import itemgetter

tuples = sorted(tuples, key=itemgetter(-1))
```

The point is that we use `key` as a function to map the elements on an orderable value we wish to sort on. With `itemgetter(-1)` we construct a function, that for a value `x`, will return `x[-1]`, so the last element.

This produces:

```
>>> sorted(tuples, key=itemgetter(-1))
[(4, 3, 1), (6, 2), (2, 3), (6, 3, 5), (5, 7), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: The function doesn't return any value in my case. The code I use is followed.

        def test(got, expected):
  if got == expected:
    prefix = ' OK '
  else:
    prefix = '  X '
  print ('%s got: %s expected: %s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected)))

def sort_last(tuples):
    from operator import itemgetter
    
    sorted(tuples, key=itemgetter(-1))

test(sort_last([(2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)]),
       [(3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])

Comment: @Sushruth: well you of course have to write the result back to `tuples`...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I feel that using [tuples.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])] would work just as well.

Comment: @Sushruth: well the `operator` package is usually faster, since usually it reduces the amount of code that has to be interpreted. A quick check says ~10-15% faster. Furthermore it *can* be dangerous (although as well wanted behavior) to sort *inplace*. The memory usage is less, but it means that other items refering to the list are now sorted as well, which can have some consequences). A final reason why `sorted(..)` can be useful over `.sort()` is that we do not always have guarantees that it is a list. We can not sort a `set` for instance, whereas `sorted` works with every iterable.

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem: True that, but right now in my case, I need to share and explain to my classmates how it works. They are not into programming as much as I am, so I think it would be better if I keep them away from such information at least until the need arises. Thanks again for your brief explanation. I'm sure it will come handy sometime.